# Word or phrase for the state in the morning after drunkenness

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, phrase-requests

I am looking for the (slang) phrase or equivalent of the word *drunkenness* which contains the word *dog*. I mean the state of someone in the morning after the hard drunkenness.

Comment: Hmm.... Doggone Drunk?

Comment: @Adel - I believe it was "after the hard drunkenness", which makes your answer invalid. Please remember to read carefully before answering. I am not flagging your answer, but please try to be careful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible you are thinking of "[hair of the dog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair_of_the_dog)". This is not the same as being drunk - it's the practice of having another alcoholic drink in the morning, in an attempt to cure your hangover from the previous night.

Comment: you are right.. I heart it. It is that I am looking for

Comment: @igor - I am glad you got your question answered, although it was not an answer to the actual question you asked.  People can get very nit-picky here, and I would hate to see you picked-on because of it.

Answer (score 5):

You may be looking for the word "hangover"

Comment: @igor A hangover is the right word here.  [a sick feeling or condition that comes after drinking too much alcohol at an earlier time](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hangover?show=0&t=1414284785)  "The hair of the mastiff that bit you" only means trying to get rid of a hangover by drinking more alcohol.

Answer (score 3):

You could possibly feel "dog-eared", which is slang for "worn down".